# Is it possible to "escape" numbers so they can be used as a variable name?

Tags: variable-definitions, variable

I would like to be able to use numbers in the names of some of my variables, it's simply easier to read that typing TwoPointZero.

Is this possible? Or is there an alternative to being able to define variables in a way where I can simply read a number.

Cheers

EDIT: Is there a way to include numeric like symbols and use them in the names of variables?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You can use `a123`. The name must start with a letter, not a number.

Comment: You can also use `a[123]` or `a[2.05]` as "variables" in most contexts. Use `=.` to clear them (not `Clear`).

Comment: @Szabolcs As ridiculous as this sounds, I actually had no idea that regarding `a123`. Thanks! Although I feel slightly silly...

Comment: You can use p or something to sub in for the decimal point too, e.g. `a2p0`

Comment: @Szabolcs Is it possible to use decimal numbers as a variable name e.g. `0.1pFdata = Import[...]`

Comment: As I said, you cannot start any name with a digit. `.` is not allowed in names.  Are you sure you shouldn't use `var[0.1]` instead or just use an association with the key `0.1`?

Comment: `.` is an operator, you cannot use operators in variables.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the information and the suggestions. @Szabolcs if you want, provide the information in an answer so I may credit you appropriately.

Comment: In your example with  `0.1pFdata` the simple check is to try to write it down and and  to try to make a simple operation, say: `0.1p=5`.  The outcome is an error message "Set::write: Tag Times in 0.1 p is Protected." The reason is that Mma understands `0.1p` as a multiplication, as it has been also mentioned before in a different form. What you certainly can is to use 0.1 as an index in such a construct, as  `Subscript[pFdata, 0.1]`, if it helps. This might be an addition to the (somewhat more safe) proposal of @ Szabolcs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YES.

Use Script Numbers like ScriptThree

```
\[ScriptThree]=4
```

Comment: You can use `\ [GothicThree]` and `\[DoubleStruckThree]` too.

Comment: Perfect, nice answer.